# Nested foreach in JTemplate

Tags: jquery, jtemplates

I need to show data with multiple records where each record further has mutiple values in array.

I am trying the code like this:

```
{#foreach $T.Data as item extData=$T}

{#foreach $T.item.Items as item1}

//data
{#/for}
{#/for}
```

It is giving one iteration for the outer loop correctly but and then stops.

Is there any way out to get it going in template file?

One way is to create separate template and include in the main template but I am looking for the possibility of using nested for in Jtemplates.

Regards, Raman

Answer (score 0):

For this old question, I think something is wrong with your template.
try this :

```
{#foreach $T as item}

{#foreach $T.item.Items as item1}

//data
{#/for}
{#/for}
```